# How to export the expandable graphs

Tags: export, machine-learning

So in `Mathematica`, neural network objects appear like this:
[image]

This is rather boring, but if you click on the plus sign, it expands into a better graph:
[image]

Which is much better. However, if you use `Export[NotebookDirectory[]<>"graph.pdf",NetGraph[LinearLayer[]]]`, Only the first picture will get exported. So how do I export the second image? Direct screenshot is not an option because I need a vectorized graph.

Comment: Look at `Export[NotebookDirectory[] <> "graph.pdf", Information[net, "SummaryGraphic"]]` You can also use "FullSummaryGraphic"

Comment: @BobHanlon It works! thanks